# Get All data from two tables in .net 5 web api?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

Patient.cs  //This is Patient Model Class

```
namespace HMS.Models
{
public class Patient
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
    public string Disease { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public IList<DoctorPatient> DoctorPatients { get; set; }
    public InPatient InPatients { get; set; }
    public OutPatient OutPatients { get; set; }
  }
}
```

InPatient.cs //This InPatient Model Class

```
namespace HMS.Models
{
  public class InPatient
  {
    [ForeignKey("Patient")]
    public string InPatientId { get; set; }
    public string RoomNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfAddmission { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfDischarge { get; set; }
    public int Advance { get; set; }
    public string LabNo { get; set; }


    public Patient Patient { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Here Patient and InPatient Attribute have one-to-one relationship

ViewInPatient.cs

```
namespace HMS.Models
{
  public class ViewInPatient
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
    public string Disease { get; set; }
    public string RoomNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfAddmission { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfDischarge { get; set; }
    public int Advance { get; set; }
    public string LabNo { get; set; }
}
}
```

Here is my DbContext class

```
public class ApplicationDbContext:DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options):base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<DoctorPatient>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Doctor)
            .WithMany(dp => dp.DoctorPatients)
            .HasForeignKey(di => di.DoctorId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<DoctorPatient>()
            .HasOne(y => y.Patient)
            .WithMany(dp => dp.DoctorPatients)
            .HasForeignKey(pi => pi.PatientId);
    }
    public DbSet<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Doctor> Doctors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DoctorPatient> DoctorPatients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InPatient> InPatients  { get; set; }

    //public DbQuery<ViewInPatient> ViewInPatients { get; set; }

}
```

How to get all data of both Patients and InPatients Table like in ViewInPatient class? (I tried to create a view in sql server but in add table window it shows InPatient instead of InPatients and it return null value)

Comment: Why don't you wirte a `Linq` query to do that.... are you using `entiry framework`? Let me know so that I could help you to do that.

Comment: I'm using entity framework core @MdFaridUddinKiron. How(Where) write query within classes.

Comment: I would prefer to create a `Custom View Model` with the combination of your `Patient` and `InPatient`. In  controller I would write `Linq` to bind two model into the `Custom View Model` not in `ApplicationDbContext` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can join both models in a Linq expression and return `ViewInPatient` list:

```cs
var ViewInPatient_set =
    YourContext
    .InPatients
    .Select(i=> new ViewInPatient() 
        {
            Name = i.Patient.Name,
            // ...
            RoomNo = i.RoomNo,
            // ...
        }
    )
    .ToList();  // <-- transform to list is optional
```